# Java regex lookbehind

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I want to match a string that has "json" (occurs more than 2 times) and without string "from" between two "json".

```
For example(what I want the string match or not):
select json,json from XXX -> Yes
select json from json XXXX -> No
select json,XXXX,json from json XXX -> Yes
```

Why the third is matching because I just want two "json" string occurs without "from" inside between it.
After learning regex lookbehind, I'm write the regex like this:

```
select.*json.*?(?<!from)json.*from.*
```

I'm using regex lookbehind to except the from string.

But after test, I find this regex match the string "select get_json_object from get_json_object" too.

What wrong for my regex? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why the third example is matching.  It has `from` sandwiched in between two `json`, so wouldn't that disqualify it?

Comment: *select json,json from json XXX -> Yes* should this not be "No" then, as it has "from" between two "json"s?

Comment: Because I just want match more than 2 json without "from" string. The third example already has two "json" string occurs before.

Comment: I think as OP wants, the line should match if it finds a string where `from` does not appear between two `json` strings. @yunfan: Check my answer and let me know if this is what you wanted, else add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) for achieving this. Use this regex,

```
\bjson\b(?:(?!\bfrom\b).)+\bjson\b
```

This expression `(?:(?!\bfrom\b).)+` will match any text that does not contain `from` as a whole word inside it.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zdqvQ4/1)**

For matching the whole line, you can use,

```
^.*\bjson\b(?:(?!\bfrom\b).)+\bjson\b.*$
```

Like you wanted in your post, this regex will match the line as long as it finds a string where a `from` does not appear between two `json`s

**[Regex Demo with full line match](https://regex101.com/r/zdqvQ4/2)**

**Edit:**
Why OP's regex `select.*json.*?(?<!from)json.*from.*` didn't work as expected

Your regex starts matching with `select` and then `.*` matches as much as possible, while making sure it finds `json` ahead followed by some optional characters and then again expects to find a `json` string then `.*` matches again some characters then expects to find a `from` and finally using `.*` zero or more optional characters.

Let's take an example string that should match.

```
select json from json json XXXX
```

It has two `json` string without `from` in between so it should match but it doesn't, because in your regex, the order or presence of json and from is fixed which is `json` then again `json` then `from` which is not the case in this string.

Here is a [Java code demo](https://rextester.com/QTXWN15951)

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("select json,json from XXX","select json from json XXXX","select json,json from json XXX","select json from json json XXXX");

list.forEach(x -> {
    System.out.println(x + " --> " + x.matches(".*\\bjson\\b(?:(?!\\bfrom\\b).)+\\bjson\\b.*"));
});
```

Prints,

```
select json,json from XXX --> true
select json from json XXXX --> false
select json,json from json XXX --> true
select json from json json XXXX --> true
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this regex is exactly my wanted. But can you explain to me, whats wrong with my regex?

Comment: @yunfan: Sure, let me add explanation in my post to why your regex didn't work.

Comment: It will work for Java or any language as it is working in regex. Can you show your code that you are trying?

Comment: I'm using scala shell:  Pattern.compile("^.*\bjson\b(?:(?!\bfrom\b).)+\bjson\b.*$").matcher("select json ,XXXX,json(XXXXXX) from json XXX").find this answer is    false

Comment: You need to escape `\b` as `\\b` in Java

Comment: Check [this java demo](https://rextester.com/QTXWN15951) Working fine as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much. This two websites is very helpful for me too.